# How do I load a new Page?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i have multiple Pages (classes which derive from the Page object) in my silverlight app.
I can load one in the app.xml with this statement:
this.RootVisual = new ZoomData ();

But what should i do when i have this page loaded, and i want to navigate to another page?

Comment: Check this link : http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/160051/359133.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating your app using the "Silverlight Navigation Application" template.

This provides the basic framework to create multi-page silverlight applications.

Comment: that's a little too much for me, i'm just creating a proof of concept and i don't want to setup a new app

Comment: @Michel: If its a proof of concept the simple create a new app from the template then run it. Hey Presto it works.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up with this:

In the application_startup

```
Grid root = new Grid();
this.RootVisual = root;
root.Children.Add(new ZoomData()); // This is your first page
```

in the click event of a button

```
Grid root = Application.Current.RootVisual as Grid;
root.Children.RemoveAt(0);
root.Children.Add(new ZoomData());
```